# Testing biased coin

Tags: probability

So I am a little rusty with my statistics skills and part of one of my exercises I have to calculate a $p$-value and I have a few

The exercise is to test how unbiased a coin is. We have gotten $n=10$ and $k=3$.

The solution for this is:

For each toss, the probability to get a heads is $\theta=(0,1)$.

The null hypothesis is $H_0: \theta=\frac{1}{2}$.

$K$= Number of heads in sample. When the null hypothesis holds, $K~Bin(n,\frac{1}{2})$.

$E_{H_0}(K)=n\theta=\frac{n}{2}=\frac{10}{2}=5$

Now 
$$p=\mathbb{P}_{H_0}\{|K-5|\ge|3-5|\} \qquad (1)\\
=\mathbb{P}_{H_0}\{K\le3\}+\mathbb{P}_{H_0}\{K\ge7\} \qquad (2)\\
=\sum^3_{k=0}\binom{10}{k}(\frac{1}{2})^2(\frac{1}{2})^{10-k}+\sum^7_{k=7}\binom{10}{k}(\frac{1}{2})^2(\frac{1}{2})^{10-k} \qquad (3)\\
=\frac{11}{32}.$$

For me, the problem is that I cannot remember how do we get from step (1) to (2). I cannot remember what the rules were to open up the brackets and cannot find the terms in English to google it.

I also don't know how we got from (2) to (3). Why is the expression same $\binom{10}{k}(\frac{1}{2})^2(\frac{1}{2})^{10-k}$ for both of them even though in step (2) they are different?

Comment: $|K-5|\ge|3-5| \iff |K-5|\ge 2\iff K-5\le -2$ or $K-5\ge +2\iff K\le 3$ or $K\ge 7$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From stage (1) to stage (2) is merely a reformulation. In (1) you have the probability of the number of heads being at least $2$ away from the mean of $5$. In (2) you have the probability of having $3$ or fewer heads, plus the probability of having $7$ or more heads. Those are the same thing. (If you want to be more formal, the two events described in (2) are disjoint, so the probability of at least one of them occurring, which is (1), is equal to the sum of the probability for each of them, which is (2).)

From (2) to (3), they're just using the definition of binomial probability (there is a typo: the second $\sum$ should've been $\displaystyle \sum_{k = 7}^{10}$). It's the same formula because it's the same probability distribution. It is the index $k$ that makes the two sums count different things. The first sum goes from $k = 0$ to $k = 3$, and thus counts the probability for anywhere from $0$ to $3$ heads. The second sum (with correction) counts from $k = 7$ to $k = 10$, meaning it counts the probability of getting between $7$ and $10$ heads.